# O que é o "stdafx.h" e qual sua importância?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

Ao criar um projeto C++ no Visual Studio, ele traz uma linha automaticamente no arquivo principal:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Como estou no início do estudo da linguagem, vendo alguns "*olá mundo*", não encontrei essa linha nos exemplos.

Ao retirar essa linha, recebo o seguinte erro

> error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

Qual é a finalidade dessa linha?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Por falta de um mecanismo melhor é uma bela gambiarra para indicar que os cabeçalhos a serem usados já possuem uma versão compilada e não precisa compilá-los novamente. Coloca esta linha e o compilador sabe que pode usar os pré compilados.

Os *headers* são códigos que são necessários para uso das bibliotecas contendo estruturas, macros e assinaturas de funções. Eles são inclusos no seu código e tudo é compilado. Demora para fazer isto até porque costuma ter vários deles e alguns são bem grandes. Só que em geral eles não são alterados e a compilação deles toda vez que compila o seu código é um desperdício.

Tem como desabilitar isso no Visual Studio, mas a compilação ficará mais lenta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Por definição **"Stdafx.h"** é um **cabeçalho pré-compilado**.

**Pré-compilado** (uma vez compilado não é necessário compilá-lo novamente).
Cabeçalho pré-compilado **stdafx.h** é basicamente usado no **Microsoft Visual Studio** para permitir que o compilador conheça os arquivos que são compilados e não há necessidade de compilá-lo a partir do zero.

**Por exemplo:**
Se você estiver incluindo os arquivos de cabeçalho do Windows abaixo
Código:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main() {  //your code return 0; }
```

O compilador sempre compilará esses arquivos de cabeçalho do zero.
Mas se você incluir **#include "stdafx.h"** antes que isso inclua, então o compilador irá encontrar os arquivos de cabeçalho compilado do **stdafx.h** e não compilado a partir do zero. Mas se o compilador não encontrar quaisquer arquivos de cabeçalho compilado do **stdafx.h**, em seguida, primeiro ele compila os arquivos e, em seguida, armazena sua versão compilada em **stdafx.h**. Para que possa ser usado para a compilação da próxima vez.

**Código:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main() { //your code  return 0; }
```

**Quais são os seus benefícios:**

> - Reduz o tempo de compilação.
> - Reduz o processamento desnecessário.

**Portanto a conclusão:**

> Usar **#include "stdafx.h"** onde você está realmente usando os outros
>   arquivos de cabeçalho (como arquivos de cabeçalho do Windows). Caso
>   contrário, não há necessidade de usar **stdafx.h**. E isso não
>   significa que você irá removê-lo de seu projeto, mas você pode
>   desativar este cabeçalho pré-compilado de configurações do projeto,
>   selecionando o arquivo (em que você não precisa deste **stdafx.h**) e
>   vá para propriedades dele e encontrar sob a opção **"C ++ ->
>   Precompiled Header e selecione Use Precompiled Header to..."**.

É isso aí. Espero que tenha entendido.