# Dúvidas sobre "linkagem"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, linkagem

Tentei passar para IDE um código que encontrei em um livro e surgiram algumas dúvidas.

Código:

newApplication.cpp

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "GradeBook.h"

int main()
{
    GradeBook gradeBook1("CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming");
    GradeBook gradeBook2("CS102 Data Structures in C++");

    cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: " << gradeBook1.getCourseName()
         << "\ngradeBook2 created for course: " << gradeBook2.getCourseName()
         << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

GradeBook.h

---

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using std::string;

class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook(string name);
    void setCourseName(string name);
    string getCourseName();
    void displayMessage();

private:
    string courseName;
};
```

GradeBook.cpp

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include "GradeBook.h"

GradeBook::GradeBook(string name)
{
    setCourseName(name);
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName(string name)
{
    courseName = name;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
}
```

1) Como o compilador consegue "saber" que a implementação do metodo está em `GradeBook.cpp` sendo que no `main()` só existe o include de `GradeBook.h`?

2) A aplicação só funcionou apos eu incluir `#include "stdafx.h"` no arquivo
`GradeBook.cpp`. Por que isso acontece?

Estrutura das pastas do Visual Studio 2017

```
-Dependencias Externas
-Arquivos de Cabeçalho
  *GradeBook.cpp
  *GradeBook.h
  *resource.h
  *stdafx.h
  *targetver.h
-Arquivos de Origem
 *newApplication.cpp
 *stdafx.cpp
-Arquivos de Recurso
 *newApplication.rc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Como o compilador consegue "saber" que a implementação do método está em `GradeBook.cpp` sendo que no `main()` só existe o include de `GradeBook.h`?

Ele não sabe. Não precisa saber. A implementação só precisa estar lá. Na hora de compilar você diz tudo o que deseja que seja compilado. E na hora de *linkar* ele pega tudo o que está disponível e junta tudo. Nessa hora ele vê se tudo o que precisa foi disponibilizado, não importa ordem, de onde vem, nada, a não ser se está lá. Se não estiver dá um erro de *linkagem*.

Depois de compilado gera um código e fica disponível para quem quiser usar. E pode até mesmo ninguém usar. Embora em condições normais o que não for utilizado não é *linkado* junto.

> 2) A aplicação só funcionou apos eu incluir `#include "stdafx.h"` no arquivo `GradeBook.cpp` Por que isso acontece?

Já foi respondido: [O que é o "stdafx.h" e qual sua importância?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206097/101).

Comment: Apos o "compilador" encontrar a implementação dos metodos de GradeBook.cpp, ele "puxa" e junta tudo em um mesmo arquivo antes de gerar o codigo objeto ?

Comment: @Rogi93 , faz algum tempo que eu me distanciei do mundo C, e mais ainda do mundo C++, então posso estar falando bobeiras... o arquivo objeto é composto de símbolos abertos, variáveis e funções implementadas (esses dois últimos símbolos resolvidos). O linkador pega os símbolos abertos e verifica se tem algum objeto que o resolva. Então, é normal e esperado que o arquivo objeto não tenho símbolos resolvidos referente a coisas fora de seu contexto interno. Esse "puxar tudo" ocorre na linkedição, onde o executável é gerado. Deve ter algo na mina de ouro que são as respostas do Maniero, basta olhar

Comment: @Rogi93 , achei duas respostas minhas sobre o assunto. A primeira: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969, e a segunda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306915/64969 (que por sinal menciona a primeira)

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson,ajudou bastante